# Extract list elements and reformulate into a vector in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list with vector elements like

```
> l
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 5 6

[[4]]
[1] 7 8
```

And I want to extract the second element in each vector to form a new vector `l_vec = c(2,4,6,8)`. Is there a simple way in R to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `sapply(l, "[", 2)`

Comment: It works, thanks!